# Missing Schema Error in 18.04 moving launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

when I execute "gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom" I get the following error:

No such schema “com.canonical.Unity.Launcher”

Answer (score 2):

You're using commands that no longer exist.

Since Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu now uses GNOME and GDM3 as the base of the Desktop Environment, and not Unity.

This is why you are getting the errors you are - there are no Unity configuration options anymore by default, so you can't set those.

Unless you installed the now community-supported-only Unity launcher, you won't have those schemas anymore.

---

The equivalents for the GNOME dock in use are:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position POSITION`

... and the valid position values are: `TOP`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `BOTTOM`

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position 'BOTTOM' works as do LEFT, RIGHT and TOP

Comment: @blogman thanks for the info, I added that to the answer.